# Inline assembly code error

Tags: c, inline-assembly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int asm_sum(int x, int y)
{
        int ret = 0;

        __asm__ __volatile__(   "loop:\t\n"
                                "addl %0 %1\t\n"
                                "incl %1\t\n"
                                "cmpl %1 %2\t\n"
                                "jle loop"
                                :"=r"(ret)
                                :"r"(x), "r"(y)
                            );
        return ret;
}

int main()
{
        int x = 4;
        int y = 9;

        printf("asm_sum(%d, %d) return %d\n", x, y, asm_sum(x,y));


        return 0;
}
```

Above is a gcc inline assembly code, which I think is very simple, but when compile it I get the error

```
addup.c: Assembler messages:
addup.c:10: Error: junk `%eax' after register
addup.c:12: Error: junk `%edx' after register
```

anybody know what happen?????

EDIT:

Never forget the comma between operands... Also

cmp op1 op2 
jle loop

would jump to loop only when op2 is less or equal than op1.

here is the code that working:

```
int asm_sum(int x, int y)
{
    int ret = 0;

    __asm__ __volatile__(   "loop:\t\n"
                            "   addl %1, %0\n\t"
                            "   inc %1\n\t"
                            "   cmp %2, %1\n\t"
                            "   jle loop"
                            :"=r"(ret)
                            :"r"(x), "r"(y)
                         );
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like the file you're compiling isn't the file you think you're compiling.

Comment: but `ret` is not modified during the loop

Comment: what do you mean?@keshlam

Comment: yes. it should be addl %1 %0 but still get the error @mangusta

Comment: @Jianchen why don't you add x to ret, then y to ret, `"addl %1 %0\t\n"                                "addl %2 %0\t\n"`

Comment: @mangusta basically I want the function return x + (x+1) + (x+2) + ... + y

Comment: `%0` *might* be initialized as `ret = 0`, or it might not - it needs to be listed as both input and output, or use the `+r` constraint. You are also modifying `%1`, which is given as input-only. It's likely that the value is not preserved across the function call anyway - but again, it's just luck.

Comment: two problem 1. what does "+r" mean 2. input variable cannot be modified within the asm code?@BrettHale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, you forgot to specify commas between operands of `addl` and `cmpl` : )) took too long to notice that,  too sleepy maybe